# How do I set a dialog box to the position of the cursor?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, user-controls, mouseclick-event

I'm developing an app with WPF and I'm creating users controls in it. When I click on the rightbutton of the mouse I want to show a dialogbox in the same position as the cursor but I'm confused how to do so.

Comment: Define constructor of your form to accept coorfinates and in mouse click event pass mouse coordinates to that constructor. Inisde the constructor set form coordinates to those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following code opens a `Window` when the right mouse button was clicked. The `Window` is positioned at the mouse pointer:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  protected override void OnMouseRightButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseRightButtonUp(e);

    var mousePointerPosition = PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
    var dialog = new Window() 
    {
      Top = mousePointerPosition.Y, 
      Left = mousePointerPosition.X, 
      Width = 100, 
      Height = 100
    };
    dialog.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure what you are looking for is already available and colled ContextMenu.

```
        <Button Content="Right-click me!">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

[image]

See the following reference:

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/contextmenu/